# javascript on blur detect if button pressed

Tags: javascript

I have an input and a button.  I want the following behavior:
1. When leaving focus from the input ( on blur event ) I want to execute a certain function only if the pressing of the button caused the "on blur".  In other words in "on blur" I'd like to know what will get focus next.  If it was the button then I know the user pressed the button and I need to do something.  If the user just clicked away I don't want to do anything.

This is what I have done:

```
<td class='bid-floor-col' >
    <input  type='text' class='bid-floor-input display-none' data-id='<%=ads.id %>' value='<%= display_price_floor(ads) %>' orig_value='<%= display_price_floor(ads) %>'/>
    <button class='bid-floor-save display-none' data-id='<%=ads.id %>'>save</button>
</td>
```

The javascript interaction is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bid-floor-input').on('blur', function()  {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $('.bid-floor-input[data-id=' + id + ']').addClass('display-none');
        $('.bid-floor-save[data-id=' + id + ']').queue(function (next) {
          $(this).addClass('display-none');
        })
        $('.bid-floor-renderer[data-id=' + id + ']').removeClass('display-none');
    });
    $('.bid-floor-save').on('click', function()  {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $('.bid-floor-save[data-id=' + id + ']').clearQueue();
        console.log('saving id ' + id);
    });
});
```

Basically, within the "on blur" I make the button invisible with a delay.  If the button gets focus within that time it clears its queue thereby keeping itself visible.

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post and I did read that.  What is the issue with my post?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service**. You have to show that you've put some efford into solving your own problem.

Comment: what exactly you want to do on click of button , this seems to be a tricky use case ?

Comment: In my updated example above what I want to do is reflected by the console.log() call.

Answer (score 1):

Try by using [activeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/activeElement)

```js
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(document.activeElement)
  }, 500)
})
```

```html
<div>
  <input type='text' id='test'>
  <button type="button">Click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Well done! But judging from the story, wouldn't it be easier to just check if the input had focus on button click?

Comment: as soon as you click on the button the focus will on button

Comment: Being a total newb to javascript.  What you're suggesting above is that I post my function for delayed execution and within that function check whether the button didn't receive focus.  My problem is that during "on blur" the code should by DEFAULT make the button disappear, and only keep it visible if it is the target of the next click.  I think your example assumes that the button stays visible.

Comment: @TervelAtanassov this code show how to get the next active element, you can get  the id or any selector from the active element and do what ever you like with that element

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`event.relatedTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FocusEvent/relatedTarget) to get the event target receiving focus.

```html
<input type="text">
<button id="btn">Button</button>
<script>
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  console.log("click");
  //do something here
});
input.addEventListener("blur", function(e){
    console.log(e.relatedTarget);
   if(!e.relatedTarget||e.relatedTarget.id!="btn"){
  console.log("blur");
  //do something here
  }
});

</script>
```